# Test Time Augmentation on Validation set?

Tags: machine-learning, validation, data-augmentation

In the traditional usage of data augmentations, we augment only the train set examples, in order to keep the distribution of the validation and test set equal.

In the TTA method, we apply augmentations on the test set of the model and average the results in order to get more accurate results.

Why aren't we applying augmentations to the validation set as well, in this method? We are applying them to the training set, and to the final test set. But when we validate the model metrics on the validation set while training, the metrics does not really reflect how the model is going to generalize on the test set, because we're going to apply augmentations on the test set.
What am I missing?